# Calculating the area of raster within polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, area

I have a raster layer with values of energy demand in each cell. I would like to know the area of the raster within each polygon (see screenshot). Any suggestions on a simple approach for this?

[image: raster with energy demand; overlaid by polygons.]

Comment: Try to use `zonal statistics` in raster menu in QGIS

Comment: "I would like to know the area of the raster within each polygon"  - for most of your polygons that's just the area of the polygon, since the raster extent spans most of your polygons. Did you mean the area **of non missing data** raster cells (the white areas) within each polygon?

Comment: Well actually the screenshot is only part of the complete layer. I would need to know the actual area of the raster layer within each polygon - excluding the no data area.